# PHP, better to set the variable before if or use if/else?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

So a simple one that I just never could find a straight answer on.

What is better (performance or otherwise):

```
$var = false;
If ($a == $b) {
    $var = true;
}
```

or

```
If ($a == $b) {
    $var = true;
} else {
    $var = false;
}
```

I've heard arguments for both ways. I find the first cleaner to ensure I have it set, and a little less code too. The pro being that you may only need to set it once without conditional. But the con being that if the argument is true, it gets set twice.

I am assuming the second way is probably best practice

Comment: Micro optimization and in 9999/10000 scenarios there is no actual performance gains...

Comment: Well in that specific case, `$var  ($a == $b)` would sure be better... Performance-wise, @jishi is right. Other than that, first way makes it clear the variable is initialized, second makes the control flow clearer... I'd go for the second one.

Comment: I think there are a lot of ways to do such things. But i think its better if you have a good structure you define $var on top and set the variable when they change. So you know that the variable has a defined value on top and you can search problems when the variable has some strange values. And you cannot forget to set it and you avoid notices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clarification: I don't think there is any performance gain, so that's why I think this is 100% subjective and depending on your team (like indentation, and where to put your mustaches ({) ). Its style.

That said, the first would be my option if there is a really definate default, and only in some extreme case (like "name == 'specialname') the assignment is used.

The second if for every run it is either this or else that. So it could depend on the meaning of the code in real life scope.

Comment: I'll clarify, but the question was performance OR OTHERWISE. There is obviously little or no performance to be gained, so it is otherwise. And that is subjective.

Comment: personally i think your incorrect, there are other factors within programming that can determine the *otherwise* statement.

Comment: to be honest, it's ignorance based question

Answer (score 10):

I believe there is no performance difference in such cases or it's negligible. However, I think that for initialization the clearest way is to write

```
$var = ($a == $b);
//or
$var = ($a==$b) ? true:false;
```

Comment: Yes, a thousand times yes. Everytime I see `if (condition) x = true; else x = false;` I want to cry.

Comment: the simple `$var = ($a == $b);` is the beauty here, the problem is that it may not be easily understandable to some programmers but the majority should be with it :) +1

Comment: I only use shorthand in view files normally, leaving the controller code easier to read with full if statements. But I think this is also dependent on your project. In this case it is a cart that is designed to be developer friendly, so full if statements would be easier to read IMO.

Comment: doesn't answer the question...just makes me realize I was hunting the wrong question in the first place! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

I my opinion the **first code** is better.

If you accidentally write an IF that doesn't check all cases (you forgot the final else) you will have always the the variabile with a default value setted.

Comment: That is pretty much how I think of it too. So I guess its pretty much to each their own here. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure if there is an exact definite answer.  However, I would answer with this - be consistent and/or follow your company's dev guidelines.