# Variables: overwriting vs if/else

Tags: php, if-statement

This is a PHP question but is probably applicable to other languages.

Which is a better way to handle variable assignments?

```
// Use default value and overwrite
$var_one = 'x';
if ($var_two) {
    $var_one = 'y';
}

// Use complete if/else
if ($var_two) {
    $var_one = 'y';
} else {
    $var_one = 'x';
}
```

I'm always curious about how software works at the lowest levels.

Comment: There are several ways you can do. First one is my way too. Also `$var_one = ($var_two?'y':'x');` is an oneliner

Comment: Better how? For writer? Reader? Compiler? Mostly it's an opinion based question

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Yeah good question; I'm thinking mostly about performance here. But if the performance wins are so negligible that readability is the real gain, I was curious to see what everyone preferred.

Comment: Ah, after looking a bit longer, I found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341716/php-better-to-set-the-variable-before-if-or-use-if-else

Comment: I should mention that though there is a fair amount of opinion here, I mean to ask which of my two code examples are fundamentally better performing for the compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use the first one because it will remove one process. Also it is cleaner than the second one:

```
$var_one = 'x';
if ($var_two)
     $var_one = 'y';
```

Or

```
$var_one = ($var_two ? 'y' : 'x');
```

The above code is even cleaner than my #1 example.

Comment: How does the first one remove a process? In terms of performance the second one removes a process, as the first has an extra step.

Comment: As i know, Second one need to run another block(else section). and removing a block of coding is a process which we can prevent execution process of that

Comment: @MajidAbbasi It's not possible to execute the sections in both the `if` and `else` blocks. The first block can have 2 assignments and a Boolean condition check while the second block has 1 assignment and a Boolean condition check.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek can you please explain more, if we remove else section we did not remove any process? Thank you in advance for your great notes

Comment: @MajidAbbasi No because the code snippet without the `else` does a assignment first, while the other snippet does not.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek according to your explanations $var_one = ($var_two ? 'y' : 'x');  is more better than others? and #1 and #2 does not have any different on execution time and second one just have small code?

Comment: @MajidAbbasi I thought you where talking about the snippets that the OP asked about? That is what the OP asked about anyways.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek Wieczorek My reason for asking these questions from you is understanding your opinions

Comment: This answer reduces cyclomatic complexity https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity which is great. Having said this, the body of each control MUST be enclosed by braces. This standardises how the structures look, and reduces the likelihood of introducing errors as new lines get added to the body. See https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md#5-control-structures. Finally - there is no need for the brackets in the ternary operator.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the second one

```
if ($var_two) {
    $var_one = 'y';
} else {
    $var_one = 'x';
}
```

I think it is more readable and lower CPU consumer because only one assignment executed at each time. But in the first one when the if is true two assignment executed.

Answer (score 2):

The second option is actually slightly faster as it only does one variable assignment when `$var_two` evaluates to `true` while the lower level jump operations are comparable in both cases.

On a side note, be careful how conditions like `if ($var2)` are evaluated as there are many cases that you may not expect to mean `false` that do.  The PHP manual has a [great page](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) to clarify that.

Comment: agree I think `isset` is good to use here

Answer (score 1):

Its depend which variable you are accessing.

If variable you are accessing is pre-populated then use below example

```
if(isset($_POST['formValue'])) {
   $formValue = $_POST['formValue'];
}
else {
   $formValue = NULL;
}
```

If you have to define variable in same page then

```
$formValue = 'x'; 
if(isset($var_two)) {
   $formValue = 'y';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the ways you define are valid and good, One more ways to do this is `ternary operator`.

Here you override the assigned variable with another one 'y' depending on the `$var_two`

```
$var_one = 'x';
if ($var_two)
    $var_one = 'y';
```

Use complete if/else, Here you just assign a value to `$var_one` depending on `$var_two`.

```
if ($var_two)
    $var_one = 'y';
else
    $var_one = 'x';
```

As i said you can do this using `ternary operator`, see the example, **override**. the existing variable.

```
$var_one = x;
$var_one = ($var_two) ? 'y' : $var_one;
```

again, **assignment** variables with new values.

```
$var_one = ($var_two) ? 'y' : 'x';
```

> **Note:** Its depend on the code what i need to compare with each other, There
>   are two types, one is assignment and another is override, I must
>   prefer `ternary operator` if less complexity, either the straight
>   forward ways `if.....else`.

Comment: which one is better than other in your opinion?

Comment: Its depend on the code what i need to compare with each other, There are two types, one is assignment and another is override, I must prefer `ternary operator` if less complexity, either the straight forward ways `if.....else`.